# Python: Recursion, I keep getting the wrong value, what I can do?

Tags: python, recursion

```
def answer(): 
    if True:
        ans = raw_input('Enter y/n:')

        if ans != "y" and ans != "n":
            print "Try again"
            answer()
        elif ans == "n":
            return False
        elif ans == "y":
            return True
if answer():
    print "It's working!, you entered Y"
else:
    print "You entered N"
```

When I execute this code, I press Enter several times or enter wrong letters, then I enter y, I always get "You entered N" instead of "It's working!, you entered Y" .

I can't figure out what's the problem, please help me.

Comment: Why the if true on line 2?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are discarding the return value of your function in the `if` block. You should change it to:

```
if ans != "y" and ans != "n":
    print "Try again"
    return answer()
```

If you don't return the value, your function will return `None`, which will be evaluated as `False` on the outer `if`. Also, there is no need of `if True:` inside your function.

P.S: Please avoid using recursion for this task. You can easily do this with a `while` loop, which iterates till the user doesn't pass correct input, and breaks as soon as succeeds. Also, give user a certain number of attempts to pass correct inputs, to avoid infinite loop.

Comment: I don't think recursion and user input are a good combination: you could blow the stack.  I'd use `while True:` instead.  (I know you're just solving the user's problem in context, of course.)

Comment: Thanks, I know now where the problem is coming form (a lot of None, shows up when I replaced return answer() by print answer() ). I'll try to fix it.

Comment: @DSM. Of course you are right. Generally, it should be prefered to give user a certain number of maximum tries to give correct input, to avoid blowing of stack.

Comment: @Salah. Printing the result will also not work. Because you are again not returning the return value of the function to the function lower on the stack, which invoked it.

Comment: @Salah. Maintain a `count` variable accross function calls. You can pass it as parameter. Start with `0`. And then for each invocation, increment it and pass - `count += 1 \n answer(count)`. And then before the invocation of function, check the value of `count`. If `count >= maxAttempt`, then `return False`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need recursion in this case, just use an infinite loop and don't return  if the answer is not "y" or "n":

```
def answer(): 
    while True:
        ans = raw_input('Enter y/n:')
        if not ans or ans not in "yn":
            print "Try again"
        else:
            return ans == "y"  # This is more succinct

if answer():
    print "It's working!, you entered Y"
else:
    print "You entered N"
```

Comment: The problem with one, it doesn't handle the case of hitting "enter" without entering a value, which equal to None,  and it will return  "You entered N"

Comment: You're right, I edited the function to take that into account :-)